# Can I set global variables and use them in other document ready events?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am using jQuery 1.6.2 and ColdFusion 9.

When a page is requested, many files are included. Several files contain the jQuery document ready method.  I want to set some global variables that I can use throughout the entire page.  For example, I want to use these variables for my slides:

```
 SlideUpRate = 400;
 SlideDownRate = SlideUpRate * 2;
```

It seems that this works inconsistently.  Is there a way to make it work consistently?

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Answer

In the index.cfm file, I set my global variables that can be used and reused in other jQuery throughout the rendered page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var SlideUpRate = 250;
var SlideDownRate = SlideUpRate * 2;
var HideRate = 250;
var ShowRate = HideRate * 2;
var ImageUnsaved = "layout/checkbox_unsaved.png";
var ImageSaved = "layout/checkbox_saved.png";
$(document).ready(function() {

   // other jQuery stuff

});
```

Comment: "It seems that this works inconsistently." Really? How so?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes you can by adding them to the global namespace:

```
var globalVar1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    globalVar1 = "something";
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(globalVar1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QDPAm/

If you don't want to pollute the global scope with multiply variables you can make an object to contain these variables:

```
var vars = {};
```

And then in your `ready` functions add variables to the `vars` object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    vars.my_variable_1 = "something";
});
```

And another `ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(vars.my_variable_1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aalouv/QDPAm/1/

I cant see why your example shouldn't work. Maybe because your are trying to access some variables before they are set?

```
var vars = {};
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(vars.my_variable_1); // undefined
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    vars.my_variable_1 = "something";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aalouv/QDPAm/3/

Also creating variables without the var indicator first will add the variable to the global scope, So you can access the variable with: `window` or just without any namespace before.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    my_variable_1 = "something";
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(window.my_variable_1);
    alert(my_variable_1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aalouv/QDPAm/2/

Comment: Thanks! Your examples and explanations were very clear and helpful.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Evik,

I'd use a object literal to store you local variables like so:

```
  var pageProperties = {
    slideUpRate: 250,
    hideRate: 250,
    imageUnsaved: "layout/checkbox_unsaved.png",
    imageSaved: "layout/checkbox_saved.png",

    getSlideDownRate: function() {
        return slideUpRate * 2;
    },

    showRate : function() {
        return hideRate * 2;
    }
  };
```

Now when you want to access these page level properites you'd use the object literal:

```
pageProperties.slideUpRate;
pageProperties.getSlideDownRate();
```

One benefit you'll get by putting the calculated rates in a function is that you can encapsulate the functionality and make these functions more maintainable and portable.

Another thing I'd do is clean up the multiple $(document).ready functions by using more object literals as discussed in this blog post by Rebecca Murphey: http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/2009/10/15/using-objects-to-organize-your-code.