# jQuery Variables: Setting variables for the entire file

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Can you set variables in the beginning of a file to be set through out?

Example:

```
var works = $('#id1'); 
var span = $('.icon');

works.focus(function() {
    if(this.value.length == 0)
    span.hide();
});

works.keyup(function() {

if(this.value.length > 0 && !span.is(':visible'))
        span.stop().show();
    else if(this.value.length == 0)
        span.stop().hide();
});
```

The variable span inside the function doesn't work. Instead of adding `var span = $('.icon');` in each function is it possible I can make it work?

Thanks alot

Comment: The variable span inside the function exists. Be more specific.

Comment: But doesn't work ? So for this example, on id1 focus, if the value =0, span doesn't hide.

Comment: What error do you get in the console ?

Comment: I would personally use namespacing, but that's a matter beyond the scope of the comment. In the meantime, I'm guessing that you're simply trying to declare those variables before jQuery is ready and available. It's probably a timing issue not a scope issue.

Comment: Set them as global variables see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065883/can-i-set-global-variables-and-use-them-in-other-document-ready-events/7065907#7065907

Comment: @jQuerybeast if the value is 0 then the length of the string "0" is 1 not 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have global variables, but if you initialize them in a `<script>` block in the `<head>` they'll be empty.  The DOM won't have been loaded.

You can instead do this:

```
$(function() {
  var span = $('.whatever');

  $('something.else').click(function() {
    // span will work here
  });

});
```

Not quite the same as globals, but in a way that's better since true globals are kind-of a bad idea. Anything declared with `var` inside the `$(function() { ... })` code will be effectively global to all code in that initialization function.

Oh, and note that putting the initialization code in a function invoked with `$()` is the jQuery way of deferring execution until the DOM is ready.  That will work in a script in the `<head>`, and it'll also work if you import your scripts at the end of the `<body>` as many luminaries now advise.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would declare them first, then set them later when the DOM is ready.

```
<script>
    var myFunVariable;
    var anotherVariable;

    $(function(){
        myFunVariable = $("#someElement");
        anotherVariable = $("#anotherElement").children();
    });
</script>
```